# Android Application that periodically gets Location

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to build an **Android Application** that retrieves the users location for every 'x' seconds and then displays it in a toast.

There are three main java files that I am using in my code. They are: `MainActivity.java` which *extends Activity* and uses the alarm service provided by the `AlarmReciever.java`, `AlarmReceiver.java` extends the broadcast receiver and `LocationModules.java`, *extends Service and implements location listener*, which contain code to retrieve location.

The sequence of flow is as follows:

> MainActivity.java ------> AlarmReceiver.java ------> LocationModules.java

`LocationModules.java` has a location manager that needs the application context which needs to be passed from `MainActivity.java` (I am not sure if I am right here).

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
 myLocationManager=(LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `LocationModules` extends `Service`, then you can just use `getSystemService` method (I mean, call it without using `mContext`).

Comment: tried doing that but still throws the same exception:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: Where do you initialize `myLocationManager`? Can you paste your code?

Comment: Also, can you post code related to the service declaration from the AndroidManifest?

Comment: hey @smb I got this straight from your answer thanks . issues has been solved. I will upload my project on guithub and post the url once am done